# C++ filesystem create_directory_symlink operation not permitted

Tags: c++

Im creating code that is supposed to be able to interact with filesystem. I can create sym link to almost every folder but in some folders the std::filesystem::create_directory_symlink is gonna throw an error saying `Operation not permitted [/home/progtest/] [/home/progtest/test]`. When Im trying to do the same in some other folder its working perfectly. I think that the problem is that the "a.out" file is in this directory.

Here is following code I made.

```
    if ( filesystem::is_directory(path_target) ) {
        try {
            filesystem::create_directory_symlink(path_target, name);
        } catch (filesystem::filesystem_error &e) {
            cout << e.what() << endl;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    else{
        try {
            filesystem::create_symlink(path_target, name);
        } catch (filesystem::filesystem_error &e) {
            cout << e.what() << endl;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Folder with a.out - /home/progtest/

```
    total 457
    drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   4096 May 27 20:27 Abs_Classes
    -rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 323760 May 31 00:26 a.out
    drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   4096 May 29 12:26 cmake-build-debug
    -rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    473 May 20 01:34 CMakeLists.txt
    -rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    296 May 20 01:38 Makefile
    -rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   7509 May 20 02:00 README.md
    drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   4096 May 31 00:25 src
    -rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf      0 May 31  2020 test.txt
    -rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 115672 May 18 03:12 zilinjak.zip
```

And folder where Im trying to create an symLink is the same Im trying to create link on /home/progtest/ and create this link inside of this folder.

ls -l of /home/ folder:

```
    total 8
    drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 May 31 12:46 progtest
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 May 31 12:49 test
```

Comment: Please run `ls -l` on the parent directory **of the target** and post the line in the output that corresponds to your target.

Comment: @Kerek I have added ls -l of the folder im trying to create symlink.

Comment: Also of the target file itself. The error indicates that you don't have sufficient permissions to create a symlink **to** the file/folder. When I will know all the permissions you have on that file, I will be able to make a simulation of that!

Comment: @Kerek Done, thanks for your help. Btw Im having an problem with filesystem::rename now aswell. But I will deal with this by myself. Thanks !



Edit: The problem might be that im trying to make an symLink inside of an vbox shared folder. Im using VBox on win.

Comment: Can be the same problem, rename is even more difficult in the area of permissions.

Comment: You should look if your user is part of the group `vboxsf`, if it isn't, then you have no permissions on these files (denoted by the `---` in the end of the permissions parts of each line)